# How to you use the space and sign flags when formatting an integer?

Tags: java, formatting

For this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%+(d", 14));
    System.out.println(String.format("%+(d", -14));
    System.out.println(String.format("% (d", 14));
    System.out.println(String.format("%+ (d", -14));
}
```

The output is

```
+14
(14)
 14
[An exception is thrown]
```

According to [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), as the **Flags** section describes, I can use the `+`,  (i.e. space) and `(` signs\flags to format integers as shown in the code above.

My questions are:

1. Where is stated how does these flags interact with each other ?
2. Why does the `space` flag work fine for the 3rd statement but throws an exception for the 4th ?
3. For the second statement, why did the `(` flag override the effect of the `+` flag ? Why isn't it the other way around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) you referenced explicitly says:

> If both the `'+'` and `' '` flags are given then an `IllegalFormatFlagsException` will be thrown.

It also lists the following restrictionm, which doesn't apply to your example:

> If both the `'-'` and `'0'` flags are given then an `IllegalFormatFlagsException` will be thrown.

If you want to see the effect of the various flags, here is a little test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("%d");
    test("%+d");
    test("% d");
    test("%(d");
    test("%+ d");
    test("%+(d");
    test("% (d");
    test("%+ (d");
}
private static void test(String fmt) {
    try {
        System.out.printf("%5s: '" + fmt + "'%n", fmt, 14);
        System.out.printf("%5s: '" + fmt + "'%n", fmt, -14);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.printf("%5s: %s%n", fmt, e);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
   %d: '14'
   %d: '-14'
  %+d: '+14'
  %+d: '-14'
  % d: ' 14'
  % d: '-14'
  %(d: '14'
  %(d: '(14)'
 %+ d: java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: Flags = '+ '
 %+(d: '+14'
 %+(d: '(14)'
 % (d: ' 14'
 % (d: '(14)'
%+ (d: java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: Flags = '+ ('
```

As you can see, it makes sense that `'+'` and `' '` are mutually exclusive. They both define how the sign of a positive number should be displayed.